# how to create Robots.txt fole in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, robots.txt

how to create Robots.txt file in Laravel??
when i try to access my Robots.txt file by url it show blank page

```
https://wallpaperaccess.in/robots.txt
```

Comment: /public/robots.txt  is where the file would live in the file system to be accessible from https://example.com/robots.txt

Comment: example.com/robots.txt show blank page and when i enter example.com/public/robots.txt thats work

Comment: sounds like you have a configuration issue with your server.  it should be pointing inside the public folder as your document root